# Cython how to create an anonymous union inside of a struct?

Tags: python, c, cython

I want to create the following structure in cython (actually I don't really need this one in but it is a simplified example.)

```
cdef struct MyStruct:
    int x
    union:
        int y
        long z
```

I can fix it by doing the following.

```
cdef union MyUnion:
    int y
    long z

cdef struct MyStruct:
    int x
    MyUnion u
```

However the issue is that if I want to access y or z I would need to say `struct_var.u.y` rather than `struct_var.y`.  Is there a way to create anonymous unions inside of a struct?

Comment: I think the answer is simply "No", Cython doesn't support this. You should be wrapping this kind of think up in a Pythonic wrapper anyway - that's kind of the point of Cython.

Comment: What do you mean by a Pythonic wrapper? Can you please provide an example? I fail to see a way to wrap anonymous structs / unions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interfacing with an external library, you can simply flatten the structure. Cython just needs the names and types for lexical lookup.

```
cdef struct MyStruct:
    int x
    int y
    long z
```

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the point of the `union` ?

Comment: @h0r53 I've editted the answer to be more clear. It only applies if they're trying to interface with an external library